# Weird mesh artifacts on just a single component in render. (All the other components have the same material but they render fine)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, topology

"Why do I get weird artifacts in my Blender render for a robot with metallic material, despite looking okay in the viewport? I've changed the color of the problematic element to yellow. I've checked the lighting, mesh topology, and material settings, but the issue persists. Is there anything else I need to consider, such as render settings or graphics card drivers? Any advice would be greatly appreciated."
[image: In the viewport]

---

[image: The issue]

[The blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1An8Gnv1EDJ7Zh1V-P6Edvxm6avQmFdn1/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the *Disable in Renders* option of *Cylinder.008*:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much. I forgot to delete it :(